# No me deja poner la clave del superusuario en shell de postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Recien descargue e instale postgresql, e inicio el shell de posgresql y cuando me va a pedir la contraseña del root, simplemente no me deja escribirlo, tecleo y nada. También si inicio el pgAdmin tampoco me deja escribir consultas en la ventanilla SQL.

[image: Error]

Comment: ¿Tienes un usuario llamado root creado en la BD?

Comment: Hola, no, solo tengo un usuario llamado postgres

Comment: Entonces no coloques root en el usuario, por pgadmin te puedes conectar?

Comment: Si, ya vi lo del Shell y si puedo conectarme por pgAdmin. Gracias

Comment: puedes mostrar el problema del pgadmin?

Comment: Lo del pgAdmin fue una equivocación mia, crei que se podia escribir consultas en la ventana SQL pero tenia que abrir el Query Editor. Muchas gracias igualmente por asistirme. ¿Cómo cierrto el tema?